# nginx: redirect nodejs served domain to subdomain

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm using NodeJS to run a server and my server uses NGINX

So running an AngularJS and Express application my `server` (api) side of the application is accessible at `https://domain.com/api` which the `api` is a directory within `server`

[View Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSiYD.png)

I'm trying to do the following, serve the node application as it normally is AND serve `https://domain.com/api` as `https://api/domain.com/`

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        root /var/www/domain.com/dist;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        ssl on;
        # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        rewrite ^/api/(.*) http://api.domain.com/$1 break;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

I've tried different versions of `rewrite ^/api/(.*) http://api.domain.com/$1 break;` including

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) http://api.domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

But still when I try an API endpoint I get 404

Comment: You can't "serve https://domain.com/api as https://api/domain.com/" if you want people to access it over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra server block that defines how you want to serve `api.domain.com`.  So if domain.com/api already works, you can add this server block to serve api.domain.com:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.domain.com;
    # include SSL stuff here
    location / { 
        # proxy_pass https://domain.com/api$request_uri;
        # or
        return 301 https://domain.com/api$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the proxy pass I get 502 Gateway error but when using return 301 this just forwards the api.domain.com to domain.com/api and the url bar reflects this update. Is there a way to not have the address bar updated?